# During a mail merge, how to send a single email to a user instead of multiple ones?

Tags: email, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-office-2013, mail-merge

I have a table that looks somewhat like this:

```
User Email   |   Invoice Number   |   Company
  A@as.com             12                 xyz
  A@as.com   |         13         |        yyy
  B@as.com   |         112        |       add
```

When I do mail merge, I do a merge field on invoice number and company and send it to the user's email. This results in A@as.com getting 2 emails for 2 different invoices; is there a way to automatically send 1 email instead?

A current solution I have is to have multiple 'invoice number' columns and transpose the column based on the user's email, however that way I lose information on which company  the invoice belongs to. Is there a better way?

Comment: What version of Office are you using?

Comment: @CharlieRB 2013 :)